# How retain Bottom Nav when navigating between page views

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 4 Pages a page view with their respective bottom navigator, At the first Index, I'm executing a function that navigates to the 4th page. However, after navigation, The bottom nav disappears, which isn't consistent. How do I make it consistent..,

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({
    Key key,
    this.category,
    this.shopname,
  }) : super(key: key); //update this to   include the uid in the constructor
  final String shopname;
  final DocumentSnapshot category;

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
```

Page controller,

```
  PageController _tabsPageController;
  int _selectedTab = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _tabsPageController = PageController();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabsPageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: PageView(
              controller: _tabsPageController,
              onPageChanged: (num) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedTab = num;
                });
              },
              children: [
```

Navigator at landing page

```
                LandingPage(), //<<================
                SavedTab(
                  shopname: widget.shopname,
                ),
                MyDrawer(),
```

Navigates to HomePage()

```
                HomeTab()      //<<================
              ],
            ),
          ),
          BottomTabs(
            selectedTab: _selectedTab,
            tabPressed: (num) {
              _tabsPageController.animateToPage(num,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  curve: Curves.easeOutCubic);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually just need the Bottom Navigator Bar that routes to the desired pages. It basically renders all the screens inside the BottomNavBar widget so the Bottom Navigation Bar is always showing. Here is an example:

```
class BottomNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavBarState createState() => _BottomNavBarState();
}

class _BottomNavBarState extends State<BottomNavBar> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  static List<Widget> _widgetOptions = <Widget>[
    Screen1(),
    Screen2(),
Screen3(),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: _widgetOptions.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
            label: 'Screen 1',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.work),
            label: 'Screen 2',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car),
            label: 'Screen 3',
          ),
        ],
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
        onTap: _onItemTapped,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Let me know in the comments if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check my code

- https://github.com/hoc081098/Movie-Ticket-Booking/blob/master/MobileApp/datn/lib/ui/app_scaffold.dart
  or
- https://github.com/hoc081098/nested_navigation

Custom Scaffold

```dart
class AppScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<BottomNavigationBarItem> items;
  final List<AppScaffoldWidgetBuilder> builders;

  const AppScaffold({
    Key? key,
    required this.items,
    required this.builders,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _AppScaffoldState createState() => _AppScaffoldState();

  static NavigatorState navigatorOfCurrentIndex(
    BuildContext context, {
    AppScaffoldIndex? switchToNewIndex,
  }) {
    final appScaffoldState =
        context is StatefulElement && context.state is _AppScaffoldState
            ? context.state as _AppScaffoldState
            : context.findAncestorStateOfType<_AppScaffoldState>()!;

    final currentIndex = appScaffoldState.currentIndex;
    final navigatorKeys = appScaffoldState.navigatorKeys;
    final newIndex = switchToNewIndex?.rawValue;

    if (newIndex != null &&
        newIndex != currentIndex &&
        appScaffoldState.mounted) {
      appScaffoldState.onTap(newIndex);
      return navigatorKeys[newIndex].currentState!;
    }

    return navigatorKeys[currentIndex].currentState!;
  }

  static NotReplayValueStream<AppScaffoldIndex> currentIndexStream(
          BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_AppScaffoldState>()!.indexS;

  static NavigatorState navigatorByIndex(
    BuildContext context,
    AppScaffoldIndex index,
  ) {
    final appScaffoldState =
        context.findAncestorStateOfType<_AppScaffoldState>()!;
    return appScaffoldState.navigatorKeys[index.rawValue].currentState!;
  }
}

class _AppScaffoldState extends State<AppScaffold> with DisposeBagMixin {
  var navigatorKeys = <GlobalKey<NavigatorState>>[];
  final indexS = ValueSubject(AppScaffoldIndex.home, sync: true);

  @pragma('vm:prefer-inline')
  @pragma('dart2js:tryInline')
  int get currentIndex => indexS.requireValue.rawValue;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    navigatorKeys = List.generate(
      widget.builders.length,
      (_) => GlobalKey<NavigatorState>(),
    );
    indexS.disposedBy(bag);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () {
        final navigatorState = navigatorKeys[currentIndex].currentState!;
        final canPop = navigatorState.canPop();

        if (canPop) {
          navigatorState.maybePop();
        }

        if (!canPop && currentIndex > 0) {
          onTap(0);
          return Future.value(false);
        }

        return Future.value(!canPop);
      },
      child: RxStreamBuilder<AppScaffoldIndex>(
        stream: indexS,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final index = snapshot!.rawValue;

          return Scaffold(
            body: buildBody(index),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              items: widget.items,
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              currentIndex: index,
              onTap: onTap,
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void onTap(final int newIndex) {
    if (currentIndex == newIndex) {
      navigatorKeys[currentIndex]
          .currentState
          ?.popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
    } else {
      indexS.add(_fromRawValue(newIndex));
    }
  }

  Widget buildBody(int index) {
    return IndexedStack(
      index: index,
      children: [
        for (int i = 0; i < widget.builders.length; i++)
          Navigator(
            key: navigatorKeys[i],
            onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
              settings: settings,
              builder: (context) => widget.builders[i](context, settings),
            ),
            observers: [
              HeroController(),
            ],
          )
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Home page

```dart
return AppScaffold(
      key: appScaffoldKey,
      builders: [
        (context, settings) => homeRoutes[settings.name]!(context, settings),
        (context, settings) =>
            favoritesRoutes[settings.name]!(context, settings),
        (context, settings) =>
            notificationsRoutes[settings.name]!(context, settings),
        (context, settings) => profileRoutes[settings.name]!(context, settings),
      ],
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
          label: S.of(context).home,
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.favorite_rounded),
          label: S.of(context).favorites,
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.notifications),
          label: S.of(context).notifications,
        ),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.person_rounded),
          label: S.of(context).profile,
        ),
      ],
    );
```